Send by ref in python to a COM
Im trying to send by ref a array of floats (or strings) but im getting a error that says the element send cant be a ctypes, must be a real.
Thats the code:
import win32com.client
import ctypes

pulse = win32com.client.Dispatch("Pulse.Labshop.Application")

def SaveMeasurement():
    FunctionO = pulse.Application.Project.FunctionOrganiser
    FunctionG = FunctionO.FunctionGroups("Test1")
    Function = FunctionG.Functions("Test2")
    MyFunction = Function.FunctionData
    Entries = MyFunction.NumberOfXAxisEntries
    entries_ref = (ctypes.c_float * Entries)(*range(Entries))

    MyFunction.Frequencies(ctypes.byref(entries_ref))

SaveMeasurement()

I get this TypeError: must be real number, not _ctypes.CArgObject
The function works on VBA and I also try on C# but I get a error on:
FunctionO.FunctionGroups("Test1")
The dll is a COM object that is used in PulseLabShop software. Using VBA allows to comunicate to an aplication. The dll have no documentation more than the one that can be obtained by dir the class.
The but the main question is if its possible to send byref a array not a Ctypes array somehow.

You stated that you got an error in your code while writing in C#. Can you elaborate further on that? and you should provide the signatures of your COM functions for us to be able to help.
